# Cannot change the color of a button manually

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I have the following code :

```
Button x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
x.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

and I get the following error on the setBackgroundColor line :

```
Syntax error on token "setBackgroundColor", Identifier expected after this token
```

I'm trying to change the color code manualy, as it depends if the user has clicked on the button....

- I do have a button with the id of "button1"

Thanks!

Comment: can you post more code of this activity ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You have written this code out side of method which can not executed properly.You need to move this code inside some method

```
 public class SpinnerBuilding extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle state){

    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.id.layout);
    ...
    Button x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    x.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    }
```

Comment: You are correct!
I've put it inside a method, and it works now! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it will work:

```
b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
x.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));//you can put hex code of any color inside the quotation.For black hex code is "000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
Button x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
x.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Must work.... but since you are getting

```
Syntax error on token "setBackgroundColor", Identifier expected after this token
```

that means your statement is outside any method but inside a class block. You can't put statements into a class declaration directly. you need to put them inside method.. As @Mukesh Kumar rightly pointed.